# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming, and I am getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    atbash_encrypt_list(['hello', 'goodbye', 'huh', 'later'])
  File "/Users/sebastiandemian/Desktop/School/CSC 241/atbash_cypher.py", line 8, in atbash_encrypt_list
    return atbash_encrypt(lst)
  File "/Users/sebastiandemian/Desktop/School/CSC 241/atbash_cypher.py", line 5, in atbash_encrypt
    return s.translate(shifted_table)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

def atbash_encrypt(s):
    alphabet =         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    shifted_alphabet = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
    shifted_table = str.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
    return s.translate(shifted_table)

def atbash_encrypt_list(lst):
    return atbash_encrypt(lst)

Could anybody give me a hint to where I made the mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

You passed a list to `atbash_encrypt_list`, which passes the list *directly* to `atbash_encrypt`. Did you mean to loop over the elements instead (e.g. `return map(atbash_encrypt, lst)`)?